# what is the proper way to turn a matrix's column into a single vector in C?

Tags: c, vector, matrix, dynamic-arrays

```
int *column_to_row(int **a, int rows, int column_index)
{
// a is a the matrix,rows are the number of rows in the matrix
//column_index is the chosen column of the matrix to be turned into a vector 
     int i;
     int *b=malloc(rows*sizeof(int));// b will be my returned vector
     if(b==NULL)
     {
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }    
     for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
     {
          b[i]=a[i][column_index];
     }
     return b;
}
```

I keep getting this C2040 Error:

`error C2040: 'column_to_row' : 'int *(int **,int,int,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this function?

Comment: Nothing (syntactically) wrong with the code itself. Are you trying to call the function before it is declared (i.e. higher up in the same compilation unit/file)?

Comment: Your error shows 4 parameters being passed on whatever line you are calling column_to_row on.  Can you show the actual call? the function code itself seems fine.

Comment: @MByD don't have one yet

Comment: Besides (but this is just some minor stuff, unrelated to the actual problem): you shouldn't `exit()` from a helper function. Instead, return `NULL` so the caller can act appropriately.

Comment: @AhmedMasud thanks! that was it. I accidentally did call the function before it was declared.

Comment: Again, at least during development: Always, ever turn *all warnings on*! They are there to *help you*!

Answer (score 1):

the function works correctly.

most likely it complains because the prototype is missing.

`int *(int **,int,int,int)`  looks like function call does not agree with declaration cause it should be `int*(int **, int ,int)`